# How to find the index of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to find the index of array but i cant. Can you help me?

```
var myArray = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
  [
    [10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14]
  ]
];
```

I want to find 13 but I don't know what is index of it. I have tried to do
`var myData = myArray[3][0][0]` 
but output is 'undefined'. How to find the target index?

Comment: `var myData = myArray[3][1]`

Answer (score 0):

use `myArray[3][1][0]`

```js
var myArray = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
  [
    [10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14]
  ]
];
var myNum = myArray[3][1][0];
console.log(myNum);
```

Comment: How did you know that the brackets were missing before editing?

Comment: @Konrad by running code :)

Comment: The code was running before your changes :)

Comment: @Konrad it was not, because last `2 ]`  was missing